# What is this pipe that is going into my engine and where can I get the fitting that connects it to the engine

Tags: engine, toyota

Here is another picture-**https://drive.google.com/file/d/1-CwsOs3hH72nus928ul5MIbuf-NMynMp/view?usp=drivesdk**
[image: The pipe is and fitting is mark with the orange circle]
This is a Toyota corolla 1995 model(bubble shape). I accidentally broke this plastic fitting that connects a pipe that looks like it is coming from the throttle body and going to the engine. I want to know what is the function of the pipe going into the engine and will the car still be able to drive like this?

What is the fitting called, and how can I can replace it.

Please help I got no idea what I am doing.

Thanks in advanced!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Its a PCV valve in the valve cover, the neck has broken off in the hose, you can get a new pcv valve [at most parts stores](https://www.rockauto.com/en/catalog/toyota,1995,corolla,1.6l+l4,1434202,exhaust+&+emission,pcv+(positive+crankcase+ventilation)+valve,5052)

The link refers to the 1.6L engine, there is an option for the 1.8L engine also.

It is just pushed into the rubber grommet, if the rubber is petrified due to heat and age it may be hard to remove and may have to be broken and removed in pieces, don't forget to remove the broken neck that may still be in the hose. I would also replace the grommet if it is hardened and brittle.

Comment: Thank you for the quick response I thought it was more serious. I will buy one ASAP but I'm just curious what will happen if I drive the car like this

Comment: It may set a check engine light due to the vacuum leak at the hose. You can plug the hose temporarily.

Answer (score 3):

***Positive Crankcase Ventilation (PCV) valve !!*** The function of the PCV valve is to eliminate emissions from the crankcase and send them to the intake and therefore combust them again in another engine cycle, which makes the engine’s emissions cleaner and more effective.

If you are a diyer, replace the valve yourself, it would cost you around 5-10 dollars, including PCV valve and installation tools cost.

Nevertheless, the labor cost you ask locally, because it might be difficult to remove the old (broken) part from the crank case.

It is never advisable to use the car without the PCV valve. If you drive your car like this, the oil will be consumed more. It might pollute the environment. It is sometimes dangerous to drive because the vacuum leaks may cause misfire when accelerating, the car may response roughly.

https://mechanicbase.com/engine/pcv-valve-symptoms/

https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crankcase_ventilation_system